# Using Facebook login with Livecode

Tags: facebook, livecode

I am building a LiveCode application and am using a Facebook Library to provide a login method.

Can anyone enlighten what platform I am meant to register on my Facebook developer website in order for my app to allow logins?

Currently I am getting a message in my imbedded browser that is launched: "You are not logged in: You are not logged in. Please log in and try again"

Below is the URL is is using to load but it will not allow me to register this in any of the platform options.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&response_type=token&scope=public_profile%2Cpublish_actions&display=popupRemove

Note: xxxxxxx is my Facebook ID

I have an example stack that is working perfectly with the creators ID so I am very confident it has something to do with my Facebook developers App setup.

Thanks for any help that can be provided

Comment: Apps that use embedded browsers/webviews for login should use the Website platform (you can input a dummy address.) When you submit your app for review, just make it clear to them that your app is not actually a website. Since you are using the Facebook redirect URI, I don’t think that needs to be input in the settings, it should be “white-listed” by default. (But if this is causing any errors, those settings can now be found under Products->Facebook Login. If that doesn’t show in your app dashboard, then you will need to add it first.)